# What happened to DejaVu Math font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, opentype

I'm trying to identify the freely-available Opentype font sets having a consistent Opentype Math font : this kind of font, extremely easy to use with XeTeX and LuaTeX (via `fontspec`), can also be used with LibreOffice and Word (a requirement in some administratve setups).

The polish TeX user group GUST has a very active "e-foundry" group, that produced, among others, the "Opentypization" of the "classical Postscript 35", known as the "Tex Gyre" fonts, whose serif fonts have, quite notably, have nice Opentype Math-compatible math fonts.

This group also produced in 2015  an Opentype math font for the DejaVu font family (see the [home page](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/dejavu-math)). This font has also been packaged and submitted to CTAN (announcement [here](https://lists.dante.de/pipermail/ctan-ann/2015-April/008409.html)).

However, this package is no longer on CTAN (retrieving the [link](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/fonts/dejavu-math) pointed to by the announcement leads to a 404 error, ditto for the CTAN page.

Trying to retrieve it from the [home page](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/dejavu-math) leads to a login page requesting a GUST ID/Password, notwithstanding the home page statement that `[t]he DejaVu Math font may be freely downloaded`. A mail to the GUST webmaster reporting the problem still has to be answered (but that was only two days ago...).

In short, this font seems to have left the surface of the Earth. Hence two questions :

1. What happened to the CTAN package ?
2. Are there freely accessible copies somewhere on the Net ? (my Google search gave zilch...).

The first question is the most troubling...

Comment: This is a good question.  I just did some research but couldn't find anything either.

Comment: The miktex package is still available: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages, but if the reason for the withdrawal is some licensing issue I would be very careful before using the font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't think licensing is an issue.  [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts) says: *"Changes made by the DejaVu project are public domain, while the full project incorporates the Bitstream Vera license, an extended MIT License which restricts naming of modified distributions and prohibits individual sale of the typefaces, although they may be embedded within a larger commercial software package."*

Comment: @HenriMenke: But the question is about DejaVu-**Math**, which can have a quite different license. The dejavu-fonts are still there: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dejavu.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer AFAIK, all GUST e-foundry fonts are released under the SIL Open Font License.  The only reason for a retraction I could thus imagine is an incompatiblity with the license of the "parent" font (which shouldn't be the case, because MIT is very permissive).

Comment: @UlrikeFisher : thanks both for the info (I grabbed the package...:-) and the advice. Indeed, having a font you can't use for publishing is of little interest...

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question : [this](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre-dejavu-math/download/index_html) is brand new.

This page points to something called `TeX Gyre DejaVu Math (OTF), version 1.106`. The archive is dated May 16, 2006, the font and documentation being dated May 8, 2016. The font is now named "TeX Gyre DejaVu Math", contrasting with the text fonts, which are named `Deja Vu xxx`, xxx being `Serif`, `Sans` or `Sans Mono`.

This does not seem to have been uploaded to CTAN (yet).

I might have launched my search at an inconvenient moment, where the previous version of the font was no longer available (possibly for problems impeding its distribution) but the new not yet available.

I am still interested i further information.

Comment: That link leads to  a login page at the moment.

Comment: @Torbjørn T : inded ; curiouser and curiouser... I'llwrite to the authors if/when I can get a handle on their addresses...

Comment: The new release (2016-05-19) has TeX Gyre DejaVu Math, see http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/tex-gyre-math

Comment: Thanks to @egreg, which seems to have posted his information as soon as published on the CTAN news list. Now *that's* horizon scannig... Kudos !